# How to write a rock, paper, scissors game in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I´m trying to add two features: the first is when the player presses <kbd>x</kbd>, it displays the score, and the second is when the player presses <kbd>q</kbd> to quit the game.

I would like to add `x => ':SCORE'` to the `ENTRY_TO_SYM` hash, but when the player presses <kbd>x</kbd> I don´t want the computer to choose something.

```
ENTRY_TO_SYM = { 'p'=>:PAPER, 'r'=>:ROCK, 's'=>:SCISSORS, 'x' => :SCORE , 'q' => :QUIT}
VALID_ENTRIES = ENTRY_TO_SYM.keys
COMPUTER_CHOICES = ENTRY_TO_SYM.values
# WINNERS and LOSERS from the player's perspective, the first value of each
# pair being the player's choice, the second, the computer's choice.
WINNERS = [[:SCISSORS, :PAPER], [:PAPER, :ROCK], [:ROCK, :SCISSORS]]
LOSERS =  WINNERS.map { |i,j| [j,i] }

class RockPaperScissors
  def initialize
    @player_score = @computer_score = @ties = 0
  end

  def play(winning_score)
    while @player_score < winning_score && @computer_score < winning_score
      puts "Player score: #{@player_score}, " +
           "Computer score: #{@computer_score}, Ties: #{@ties}"

      player = player_choice 
      computer = COMPUTER_CHOICES.sample
      puts "\nPlayer chooses #{player.to_s}"
      puts "Computer chooses #{computer.to_s}"

      case player_outcome [player, computer]
      when :WIN
        puts "#{player.to_s} beats #{computer.to_s}, player wins the round"
        @player_score += 1
      when :LOSE
        puts "#{computer.to_s} beats #{player.to_s}, computer wins the round"
        @computer_score += 1
      else
        puts "Tie, choose again"
        @ties += 1
      end
    end
    puts "\nFinal score: player: #{@player_score}, " +
         "computer: #{@computer_score} (ties: #{@ties})"
    puts (@player_score == 2) ? "Player wins!" : "Yea! Computer wins!"
  end


  private

  def player_choice
    loop do
      print "Choose rock (r), paper (p) or scissors (s) || OPTION choose (x) if you want to display the score and (q) to quit the game : "
      choice = gets.chomp.downcase
      return ENTRY_TO_SYM[choice] if ENTRY_TO_SYM.key?(choice)
      puts "That entry is invalid. Please re-enter"
    end
  end

  def player_outcome(plays)
    return :WIN  if WINNERS.include?(plays)
    return :LOSE if LOSERS.include?(plays)
    :TIE
  end
end


RockPaperScissors.new.play(3)
```

Comment: Consider writing `WINNERS = { 's'=>'p', 'p'=>'r', 'r'=>'s' }`. Then if the variables `player` and `computer` each hold `'r'`, `'p'` or `'s'`, the player wins if `WINNERS[player] == computer #=> true`, the computer wins if `WINNERS[computer] == player #=> true`; else they throw again. Do you see how that simplifies your problem? You don't need the symbols `:ROCK`, `:PAPER` and `:SCISSORS`.

Comment: I am confused, are you using [tag:ruby-on-rails] in combination with [tag:sinatra]? And how does your question relate to those two?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this for calculating the result:

```
  values = {
  'Paper' => {
               'Paper'   => 'Ties'
               'Rock'    => 'Wins'
               'Scissors'=> 'Loses'
             }
  'Rock' =>  {
               'Paper'   => 'Loses'
               'Rock'    => 'Ties'
               'Scissors'=> 'Wins'
             }
  'Scissors' => {
                 'Paper'   => 'Wins'
                 'Rock'    => 'Loses'
                 'Scissors'=> 'Ties'
                }
  }
  ENTRY_TO_SYM = { 'p'=>'Paper', 'r'=>'Rock', 's'=>'Scissors', 'x' => :SCORE , 'q' => :QUIT}

  def player_choice
     loop do
       print "Choose rock (r), paper (p) or scissors (s) || OPTION choose (x) 
       if you want to display the score and (q) to quit the game : "
       choice = gets.chomp.downcase
       return ENTRY_TO_SYM[choice] if ENTRY_TO_SYM.key?(choice)
       puts "That entry is invalid. Please re-enter"
     end
  end
```

The wording isn't perfect and this is untested, and needs the outcomes part so fiddle with it until it works for what you want ;)